# Rails 4: Rendering new action on view that uses different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

My app has two models: users and tips. Tip belongs to user and also belongs to user as "recipient".

How it should work, is that a user can send a tip to another user by navigating to their profile page (users#show), filling out a form (single field: link) and then submitting the form. The form sets user_id to current_user and recipient_id to the user whose page you are currently on.

I'm having trouble getting the form to render on the users#show page, and to function correctly if it does load.

From my tips controller:

```
def new
 @tip = current_user.tips.build
end

def create
 @tip = current_user.tips.build(tip_params)
 @tip.recipient_id = @user

 respond_to do |format|
  if @tip.save
     format.html { redirect_to @tip, notice: 'Tip was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tip }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @tip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

On my users#show view I am rendering the form with the following:

```
<%= render '/tips/form' %>
```

And here is the form code:

```
<%= form_for(@tip) do |f| %>
  <% if @tip.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@tip.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tip from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @tip.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :link %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :link %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #1):
<%= form_for(@tip) do |f| %>
```

Which I gather is because the tip variable is not being instantiated. I tried passing a local variable to the form when rendering as follows:

```
<%= render '/tips/form', locals: {tip: current_user.tips.build} %>
```

Which allows the form to render on the page, but when I try to submit the form I get:

Routing Error: No route matches [POST] "/users/3"

Which I assume means that passing the variable locally is allowing the form to be rendered but not allowing it to communicate with the action from the tips controller. In other words, it is trying to run users#new instead of tips#new.

The only solution for this that I have been able to get to work is to duplicate the tips#new action in the controller for users, by adding this line to the users#show action in the users controller:

```
@tip = current_user.tips.build(tip_params)
```

But I'm reading that this is inadvisable because it is not DRY, although I'm not entirely sure what that means. My question is, is there another, better way to do this? Whats the DRY way to allow a user to create a new object from a view that uses a different controller?

Or am I going about this task the wrong way entirely?

Comment: Can you post your `show` action of `UsersController`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%= form_for(@tip) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= form_for(tip) do |f| %>
```

And:

```
<%= render '/tips/form', locals: {tip: current_user.tips.build} %>
```

Can be

```
<%= render :partial => '/tips/form', locals: {tip: current_user.tips.build} %>
```

Thats it!

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is this for the case in which I duplicate the tips#new action in the user controller? Or for the case in which I render the form with a local variable? I tried adding the local variable back and changing as you said but got the same error that I did last time.

Comment: `for the case in which I render the form with a local variable` can u paste your final form_for?

Comment: At time of posting my form_for was 

<%= form_for(@tip) do |f| %> 

and after your comment I changed it to 

<%= form_for(tip) do |f| %> 

and added the locals back into my render like this 

<%= render '/tips/form', locals: {tip: current_user.tips.build} %> 

I'm still getting a nil error and the line with the form_for is still the one highlighted.

Comment: can you try `render :partial => '/tips/form', locals: {tip: current_user.tips.build}`?